# Get lateral and longitudinal position of vehicles

Tags: sumo

I need to get relative lateral coordinates (distance to the vehicle from one side of the lane i.e Px) of vehicles.

[image]

I know that SUMO provides absolute [x,y coordinates and distance traveled (Py)](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/FullOutput).

Is there a way to get Px information at each timestep directly like Py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is part of the raw dump (or netstate dump, see https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Output/RawDump) but only if the sublane model is active. It is given as an absolute deviation from the center line of the line (which is always 0 if the sublane model is not active).